# ReactNative ReactNavigation Custom DrawerContent - Passing color and size to Icon

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-drawer

I was referring to an online tutorial to create custom DrawerContent for my DrawerNavigator. Am using ReactNavigation v5.

Here's my minimal code:

```
import React from 'react';

import { View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Text  } from 'react-native';

import { DrawerContentScrollView, DrawerItem } from '@react-navigation/drawer';

import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome5';

export default function DrawerContent(props) {
    return (
        <View style={{flex:1}}>
            <DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>
                <View>
                    
                    <DrawerItem 
                        icon={({color, size}) => (
                            <Icon 
                            name="calendar-alt" 
                            color={color}
                            size={size}
                            solid
                            />
                        )}
                        label="Home"
                        onPress={() => {props.navigation.navigate('Home')}}
                    />

                </View>
            </DrawerContentScrollView>
        </View>
    )
}
```

Here's the actual tutorial I followed: https://github.com/itzpradip/react-navigation-v5-mix/blob/master/screens/DrawerContent.js

My doubt is, how can I set the `color` and `size` of the `Icon`. I didn't understood the technique used in that line. I mean in that line, the `color` and `size` variable are passed to the child `Icon` element from the `DrawerItem` ? If so, where is it defined? How can I change the values?

Answer (score 2):

According to the docs the color can be set by using the activeTintColor and inactiveTintColor props of drawerItem

> - activeTintColor: Color for the icon and label when the item is    active.
> - inactiveTintColor: Color for the icon and label when the item    is inactive.

So sample code would be like

```
<DrawerItem 
    icon={({color, size}) => (
        <Icon 
        name="calendar-alt" 
        color={color}
        size={size}
        solid
        />
    )}
    activeTintColor="red"
    inactiveTintColor="blue"
    label="Home"
    onPress={() => {props.navigation.navigate('Home')}}
/>
```

As per the size its hardcoded based on the source code to 24
Line 44 of [source code](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/main/packages/drawer/src/views/DrawerItem.tsx)

Still you have the option to pass the size you want or you can pass a custom react component as the icon which will be rendered as the icon, you can use it to provide your own style.

Comment: Ok thanks. So what exactly is happening in this line `icon={({color, size}) => (` Are `color` and `size` variables here? Or it's from the parent's property? Somewhat confused here.

Comment: Color and size passed as arguments by the parent. Think of it as a function to render the icon and the parent calls it with some argument to render the icon.